# How can I force bg-primary on my ul using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a mouse-over that highlights my li using the themed bootstrap color.  However, list-group-item is overriding the background style to white.

This is for a component that will be used by multiple people and who knows what they will set their bg-primary as?  So I don't really want to force a specific color.

Is there any way to override the cascade for this case and have bg-primary override list-group-item instead of the other way around?

Here is a fiddle showing the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/scottieslg/5bqtr8dn/1/

```
<div class='container'>
  <ul class='list-group'>
    <li class='bg-primary list-group-item'>Test1</li>
    <li class='list-group-item'>Test2</li>
    <li class='list-group-item'>Test3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you write this is your css: `.bg-primary { color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; }`

Comment: @SumitSahay Like I said, this is going to be a component and someone might have overridden their bg-primary (say, to a light blue?), so I don't want to force a specific color.  That would completely break their theme.  I want to use whatever bg-primary the user has defined.

Comment: Refer this: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css
They might be using the above theme. The scenario here is css of `list-group-item` is written below `bg-primary` hence, the former gets priority. I used the above theme and placed it like that. You can use specific selector like adding an `id` to `ul` and then selecting the child elements.

Comment: Do you mean something like !important ? [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5bqtr8dn/3/).